# Delphi (Indy) Threadsafe classes

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy

Let's say I have some class, TMaster, which asa field includes a TIdTCPServer. Some method of the TMaster class is responsible for the OnExecute event of the TIdTCPServer.

Firstly, is this threadsafe and acceptible? Secondly, let's assume my class has many other private fields (Name, Date, anything...) can the OnExecute event - which is really a method INSIDE the TMaster class, write to these variables safely?

I guess I mean to ask if private fields are threadsafe in this situation?

I am really new to threading and any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Adrian!

Comment: It is thread safe if the code in your "some method of the TMaster class" is thread safe.  In other words, Indy is thread safe until it calls your code.  Once your begin is reached, thread safety is up to you.  The same applies for accessing your private fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I approach this is not to have the fields used by the events belong to the `TidTCPServer` 
owner, but define a custom `TidContext` descendant and add the fields to that class.

Then you simply set the `ContextClass` property on the server class to the type of the of your custom context. This way each Connection/Thread will get its own custom context containing  its own private fields, this way there is no issue with concurrent thread access to the same fields.

if you have a list of objects that need to be accessed by the different contexts you have two options.

1) create copies the objects and store them in a private field in for each context instance
This can be done in the `OnConnect` Event.

2) Protect the objects from concurrent thread access using a synchroniser eg `TIdCriticalSection`, `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` or semaphore,

which method you use depends on each individual situation.

if you need to manipulate any vcl components remember this can't safely be done outside the main vcl thread therefore you should create your own `tidnotify` decendants for this. performing this sort of operation using `tidsynch` can lead to deadlocks when stoping the `tidtcpserver` if it is in the middle of a vclsynch operation.

this is just some of what I have learned over the course of a few years using Indy.

Answer (score 2):

`TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component. No matter what you wrap it in, the `OnExecute` event will always be triggered in the context of worker threads, one for each connected client, so any code you put inside the handler must be thread-safe.  Members of the `TMaster` class need adequate protection from concurrent access by multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: So does this mean multiple worker threads will execute MULTIPLE instances of this OnExecute wrapper?

Comment: @Adrian every thread will execute the same OnExecute method, but have its own memory block for local variable data

Comment: Every client in the server will run in its own unique thread. The server only has one set of `OnConnect`, `OnDisconnect`, `OnExecute` and `OnException` events available, and any client can trigger those events at any time. Those events have a parameter to tell you which client is triggering the event at that moment. So yes, you can, and usually will, have multiple clients running the same event handler at the same time. That is why the bodies of your event handlers must be thread-safe. If an event handler accesses a shared variable of the `TMaster` class, that variable must be protected.